# can't print response data after sending guzzle `get` request

Tags: php, phpunit, guzzle

I was able to to get some data i wanted using `POSTMAN` after submitting this url with get params:
http://10.0.0.0/adserver/src/public?url=http://dummy.com

but when i tried sending the same request to guzzle:

```
public function testGetAds_test()
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => $this->config['base_url']]);
    $response = $client->get('getAds', ['query' => ['url' => 'http://dummy.com']]);
    $data = json_decode($response->getBody());

    var_dump($response->getBody());
}
```

i get 200 but the dump prints this insead of the data i got using `POSTMAN` :

```
.object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#41 (7) {
  ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  resource(226) of type (stream)
  ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  NULL
  ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  string(10) "php://temp"
  ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

any idea what am i missing here?? thx

Comment: I suppose the object implements `__toString()` method. Try `$body = (string)$response->getBody(); var_dump($body);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deal with a Json response you can directly call the `json()` method on the response object as described [here in the doc](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/5.3/quickstart.html#json-responses):

so you can use:

```
$data = $response->json();
```

> Guzzle internally uses PHP’s `json_decode()` function to parse
>   responses. If Guzzle is unable to parse the JSON response body, then a
>   GuzzleHttp\Exception\ParseException is thrown.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

for **var_dump()** you need to use that

```
$response->getBody()->getContents()
```